# Heroku can't find dataTables images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, datatables, asset-pipeline

When I push my Rails 3.1.0 app to heroku, some of the images cannot be found.  It seems to only be an issue for the dataTables plugin. The logs show the following:

```
heroku[router]: GET my-app.herokuapp.com/assets/dataTables/back_disabled.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=238ms status=404 bytes=728
```

I am using the jquery-ui-rails and jquery-datatables-rails gems. Here is an excerpt from my Gemfile:

```
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "3.1.4"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Everything works on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the DataTables assets are not compiled by the Asset Pipeline. You should try to add the gem **outside** the assets group so that it is loaded in production as well, then the assets should be accessible to be served.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the problem. I thought this might be the issue considering the comment above the assets group.  Do you mind explaining why the assets aren't loaded in production when they are under the assets group?

Comment: Gems in the assets group are not loaded by default in production, as Rails assumes that all of them have been precompiled and can therefore be served from the file system. I assume a gem can register it's assets for precompilation, but in the case of the DataTables gem this functionality seems not to have been added in. If it were, the image would have been requested with an MD5-Hash value at it's end, like `my-app.herokuapp.com/assets/dataTables/back_disabled-e27734b3da30013f044723f9099b9455.png`.